# wind whips on the faces of the soldiers

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

> A dusty wind whips on the faces of the soldiers.

I see sentences like "[the wind whipped their faces](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20wind%20whipped%20their%20faces%22&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS524US524&aq=f&oq=%22the%20wind%20whipped%20their%20faces%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.956j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" But I'm not sure whether the above sentence is valid. I don't see any matches in google or ngram. Is something wrong with the phrase "[the wind whips on the faces of the](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wind%20whips%20on%20the%20faces%20of%20the%22&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS524US524&aq=f&oq=%22wind%20whips%20on%20the%20faces%20of%20the%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.879j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22wind%20whips%20on%20the%20faces%20of%20the%22&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS524US524&aq=f&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbo=u&tbm=bks&source=og&sa=N&tab=wp&authuser=0&ei=yG6ZUZD0JImCiAKB_oCwCg&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.cGE&fp=370a7290b31c6440&biw=1275&bih=635) XXXXs"?

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic expression typically uses *in*, *against* or nothing.

> Wind whips their faces.
>   Wind whips *against* their faces.
>   Wind whips *in* their faces.

Comment: Or, [whips **in** their faces](http://www.google.com/#q=%22whipped+in+their+faces%22&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=74-ZUcPIMov29gTihIHwDA&ved=0CAoQ_AUoBA&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.eWU&fp=feab5470dd4dfd2c&biw=1185&bih=876).